# What's the opposite of PageReference.getContentAsPdf?

Tags: visualforce, pdf

For printable documents I usually want PDF output, but occasionally want to revert to HTML. Is there some mechanism to achieve "PageReference.getContentNotAsPDF"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<apex:page renderAs="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.renderAs}" />
```

/apex/pageName?renderAs=pdf